# how to give each application a different session?

Tags: php, session, web-applications, session-cookies, login-script

For eg

**App.1**

session_start();

$_SESSION["**user_name**"] = "xyz";

$_SESSION["**is_login**"] = True;

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

**App.2**

session_start();

$_SESSION["**user_name**"] = "abc";

$_SESSION["**is_login**"] = false;

How to use same session like above same session for different application at same time?

Comment: Two application or two domain?

Answer (score 2):

Have different session names ,that would be good.

Answer (score 1):

I would do like this:

```
$_SESSSION['current_app'] = 'app1';
```

App.1

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['app1']["user_name"] = "xyz";
$_SESSION['app1']["is_login"] = True;
```

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

App.2

```
session_start();    
$_SESSION['app2']["user_name"] = "abc";
$_SESSION['app2']["is_login"] = False;
```

To retrieve the current session:

```
$current_app = $_SESSSION['current_app'];
$user_name = $_SESSION[$current_app]["user_name"]
$is_login = $_SESSION[$current_app]["is_login"]
```

You could of course use session_name() as Orangepill stated, but then you will have to consider some things:
(Based on reading the comments from session_name() - manual - http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php)

- You must call session_name() before each session_start() and it wouldn't return an error otherwise.
- It's "expensive" (time of executing script)
- Session_name() function    will have no essential effect if you set
  session.auto_start to true    in php.ini
- You MUST use session_name() first if you want to use
  session_set_cookie_params(). PHP won't give you any errors even if
  you don't.

Answer (score 0):

Call the session_name function passing in an identifier for your app prior to calling session_start

For example

```
session_name("App1");
session_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use different session in a single application. For that you need to set you session_cookie_path differently for different session.